# Initialize a final variable with "this" in Dart

Tags: dart, final

I have a class like this:

```
class A extends B {
  final Property<bool> property = Property<bool>(this);
}

class Property<T> {
  Property(this.b);
  final B b;
}
```

But I get an error on `this` saying:

> Invalid reference to 'this' expression.

I believe I can't access `this` at that moment, probably because the object reference is not ready yet.

So I tried other forms of initializing that variable like:

```
class A extends B {
  final Property<bool> property;
  A() : property = Property<bool>(this);
}
```

But I get the same error.

The only thing that works is:

```
class A extends B {
  Property<bool> property;
  A() {
   property = Property<bool>(this);
  }
}
```

Which needs me to remove the `final` variable declaration, which is something I don't want to.

How can I initialize a `final` variable in Dart that needs a reference to the object itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reference `this` in any initializers as `this` hasn't yet been initialized itself, so you won't be able to set `Property<bool> property` to be final.

If you're just trying to prevent modification of the value of `property` from outside the instance, you can use a private member and provide a getter to prevent modification. Given your example, that would look something like this:

```dart
class A extends B {

  // Since there's no property setter, we've effectively disallowed
  // outside modification of property.
  Property<bool> get property => _property;
  Property<bool> _property;

  A() {
   property = Property<bool>(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's just that this kind of boiler plate is exactly what I was trying to avoid by creating `Property`, it's a class to encapsulate getter and setter and provide change notification all at once.

Comment: Yeah, that's totally understandable. However, this is something that you'll be able to handle in the near-ish future with [late fields](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/575f301c9947fff50e612af8dd245ad6600ff674/accepted/future-releases/nnbd/feature-specification.md#late-fields-and-variables) which are coming when the language moves to non-nullable by default. In that case, I think the following code would be valid:

```class A {
  late final Property<bool> property;
  A() {
    property = Property<bool>(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh that would be amazing!